# Oracle DECODE Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Problem:
I'm deciphering a query that as a function called DECODE. I looked up the syntax (Column, value, replacement value, default) but I do not undertand what the below syntax is doing.

Query:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND DECODE(a1.prev_start_date, NULL, 'THIS IS NOT NULL', a1.prev_end_date) IS NOT NULL
```

When I add the above syntax the below row does not display, why?

Table:

```
ID       prev_start_date    prev_end_date
456        2/13/2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what that code snippet does:

If `prev_start_date` is `NULL`, then the function returns the string `'THIS IS NOT NULL'`. That string is not `NULL`, so the condition evaluates to TRUE.

If `prev_start_date` is not `NULL` then `DECODE()` returns `prev_end_date`. The condition is TRUE only when `prev_end_date` is not `NULL`.

SO: the condition is equivalent to

```
(prev_start_date is null or prev_end_date is not null)
```

Obviously, in the example you gave, `prev_start_date` is not `NULL`, but `prev_end_date` is `NULL` - exactly the combination of values that will NOT pass the filter.

Answer (score 0):

**Records with Date Effectivity**

Typically when a record has a date effectivity (e.g. start and end date), the convention is to use the `between` condition where the end date has an `NVL` function call.

The principal is that a lot of effective date have not been end dated.

The check for a `NULL` around the start date as you showed is satisfied with this between condition (a `NULL` will be excluded).

With respect to the decode statement you displayed, it

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND DECODE(a1.prev_start_date, NULL, 'THIS IS NOT NULL', a1.prev_end_date) IS NOT NULL
```

The decode statement can be read as:

*"if start date is NULL, then 'THIS IS NOT NULL', else prev_end_date" which makes no sense.*

I would have a between condition as follows:

```
SCOTT@db>WITH test AS
  2    (SELECT hiredate prev_start_date, sysdate prev_end_date FROM emp
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT to_date(NULL,'dd-mon-yyyy'), to_date(NULL,'dd-mon-yyyy') FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT prev_start_date,
  7    prev_end_date
  8  FROM test t
  9  WHERE 1=1
 10  AND sysdate between t.prev_start_date and NVL(t.prev_end_date, sysdate);
PREV_START_DATE          PREV_END_DATE            
17-DEC-1980 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
20-FEB-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
22-FEB-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
02-APR-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
28-SEP-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
01-MAY-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
09-JUN-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
09-DEC-1982 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
17-NOV-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
08-SEP-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
12-JAN-1983 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
03-DEC-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
03-DEC-1981 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  
23-JAN-1982 12:00:00 AM  27-SEP-2017 12:40:41 PM  


14 rows selected.
```

The NULL is excluded from the result set.

Comment: Using `between` with oracle dates is often a bad idea due to the fact that oracle dates include the time.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? That with `start_date` and `end_date` the convention is to use conditions with the `between` operator? That is not true (show us where you saw such a convention) and can lead to incorrect results in many cases. The convention is that the `start_date` is included in the time interval relevant for that row, but the `end_date` is **excluded**. The common convention is to have conditions like `dt >= start_date AND dt < end_date` - notice the strict inequality.

Comment: @mathguy it is pervasive in oracle application code.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk My answer should be more nuanced.  With effectivity dates, one should look at how an application populates these columns and the business rules behind them.